# How to display webcam with high resolution in a small container

Tags: html, video, bootstrap-4, size

I'm displaying my webcam into html5 video tag as follows:

```
<video id="myWebCamVideo" muted autoplay></video>
```

The webcam resolution is 1920x1080px. The point is I want to display it as follows:

```
<div id="divVideo" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 mt-3 text-center ml-auto mr-auto">
      <video id="myWebCamVideo" muted autoplay></video>
</div>
```

But the video tag is bigger than col-lg-4 with. Is possible to display the video tag with HD in a smaller div? Or always the video tag needs the px selected?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
             <div id="divVideo" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 mt-3 text-center ml-auto mr-auto">
                    <video id="myWebCamVideo" muted autoplay style="width: 100%;">
                    </video>
             </div>
```

Give 100% width to video tag. it will set as per parent div width.

I hope it would be helpful.